# Sending HTTPS post request in android using HTTPClient for unverified certificates

Tags: java, android, node.js, android-studio, ssl

I have written this piece of code for sending the POST request to a localhost server running `nodejs` having a certificate generated using `openssl` command. But when I am trying to send the post request, I can see in android log the issue with the `trust anchor` and POST request on `https` is not working but is working if I remove the certificate from `nodejs` server and send request with `http`. I know this is because my certificate is not verified from any well known CA like verisign. So, how can I send the request to this `https` server? I also tried installing the certificate in my android phone but it didn't solved my problem either. I can post the source code of `HttpClient.java` as well.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    Button encAndSendBtn;
    TextView companyName, modelNumber, specification;

    public MainActivity() throws MalformedURLException {
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        encAndSendBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.encAndSend);
        companyName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.company);
        modelNumber = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.modNum);
        specification = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.spec);
    }
    public void onclickbutton(View view) {

        encSend scv = new encSend();
        scv.execute();
    }

    private class encSend extends AsyncTask {

        String companyNameS = companyName.getText().toString();
        String modelNumberS = modelNumber.getText().toString();
        String specificationS = specification.getText().toString();

        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground(Object[] objects) {
           JSONObject jsonObjSend = new JSONObject();
           JSONObject encrptObjSend = new JSONObject();

           try {
                jsonObjSend.put("Company", companyNameS);
                jsonObjSend.put("Model Number", modelNumberS);
                jsonObjSend.put("Specification", specificationS);

                String finalData = jsonObjSend.toString();
                Log.i("data", finalData); 
                String key = "HelloWorld321@!";
                String encrypt;
                try {
                    CryptLib cryptLib = new CryptLib();
                    String iv = "1234123412341234";
                    encrypt = cryptLib.encryptSimple(finalData, key, iv);

                    encrptObjSend.put("encrptedtext", encrypt);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                Log.i("Encrypted data", encrptObjSend.toString());

                JSONObject header = new JSONObject();
                header.put("deviceType", "Android"); // Device type
                header.put("deviceVersion", "2.0"); // Device OS version
                header.put("language", "es-es");    // Language of the Android client
                encrptObjSend.put("header", header);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = HttpClient.SendHttpPost("https://192.168.43.59:443/api/aes", encrptObjSend);
            return "success";
        }
    }
}
```

**Update:**

```
public class HttpClient {
private static final String TAG = "HttpClient";

public static JSONObject SendHttpPost(String URL, JSONObject jsonObjSend) {

    try {
        DefaultHttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpPost httpPostRequest = new HttpPost(URL);

        StringEntity se;
        se = new StringEntity(jsonObjSend.toString());

        // Set HTTP parameters
        httpPostRequest.setEntity(se);
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
        httpPostRequest.setHeader("Accept-Encoding", "gzip"); // only set this parameter if you would like to use gzip compression

        long t = System.currentTimeMillis();
        HttpResponse response = (HttpResponse) httpclient.execute(httpPostRequest);
        Log.i(TAG, "HTTPResponse received in [" + (System.currentTimeMillis()-t) + "ms]");

        // Get hold of the response entity (-> the data):
        HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();

        if (entity != null) {
            // Read the content stream
            InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
            Header contentEncoding = response.getFirstHeader("Content-Encoding");
            if (contentEncoding != null && contentEncoding.getValue().equalsIgnoreCase("gzip")) {
                instream = new GZIPInputStream(instream);
            }

            // convert content stream to a String
            String resultString= convertStreamToString(instream);
            instream.close();
            resultString = resultString.substring(1,resultString.length()-1); // remove wrapping "[" and "]"

            // Transform the String into a JSONObject
            JSONObject jsonObjRecv = new JSONObject(resultString);
            // Raw DEBUG output of our received JSON object:
            Log.i(TAG,"<JSONObject>\n"+jsonObjRecv.toString()+"\n</JSONObject>");

            return jsonObjRecv;
        }

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        // More about HTTP exception handling in another tutorial.
        // For now we just print the stack trace.
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}


private static String convertStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    /*
     * To convert the InputStream to String we use the BufferedReader.readLine()
     * method. We iterate until the BufferedReader return null which means
     * there's no more data to read. Each line will appended to a StringBuilder
     * and returned as String.
     *
     * (c) public domain: http://senior.ceng.metu.edu.tr/2009/praeda/2009/01/11/a-simple-restful-client-at-android/
     */
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    String line = null;
    try {
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            is.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

}

Comment: Can you try posting to a known site with ssl, like https://google.com, To make sure issue is with cert

Comment: And please post HttpClient.SendHttpPost source

Comment: I have added HttpClient @Skarlinski

Answer (score 0):

You should use an always-ok delegate to avoid server certificate validation. Of course you must use https connection. Check this link, for example: http://www.nakov.com/blog/2009/07/16/disable-certificate-validation-in-java-ssl-connections/

Comment: You must add to your Https connector a delegate which accepts any server certificate. Code is somewhat long, so better follow link I post or do a deeper search about 'ignoring self signed server certificate java'.I had seen this question & response previously in S.O. itself